# Converting a list of lists to table and export in CSV in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I want to convert data presented in a list of lists (JSON) in a table so that I can export it in CSV format. The following is the link to my code.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d44153ff2b315d314f68fcfe1cc90fff

There's a list called 'DataList' which I want to convert to table and export in CSV.

```
    var collection = ee.ImageCollection(sentinel.filterDate('2016-11-01','2016-11-30')
                         .filterBounds(gulbarga)
                         .sort('CLOUD_COVER_ASSESSMENT')
                         .first());
print(collection.size());
print(collection);


var data = collection.getRegion(gulbarga,30);
print(data,'DataList');
```

Comment: what isn't working?

Comment: I am not able to get as to how to get 'DataList' in a table format so that I can export it to drive.

Comment: When the question is reopened, I can provide the answer in text. For now, here is the link to rework the getRegion() output. https://code.earthengine.google.com/defdba7e5f5bd5b87b1abd967885d6f8. Although I would suggest using reduceRegions() and add the date of the image to each feature. You can then export the feature collection as CSV.

Comment: Thank you so much. this works pretty well. There's one more problem though. Can the 'time' column elements somehow be modified in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format?

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/39ee841069d9a8349a23712cfecc01ea

Answer (score 1):

To export data as a table (CSV) in the GEE, you need to make a feature collection with each feature a dictionary of properties. The getRegion() function puts out a list of which the first are the keys and the others are the values related to it. We can rework that into a featureCollection so it can be exported:

```
// get the information using getRegion()
var data = collection.getRegion(gulbarga,30);
// keys of the variables are in the first list
var keys = ee.List(data.get(0));

// make a feature collection from all the values from row 1 till end
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(data.slice(1).map(function(singleData){
  singleData = ee.List(singleData);
  var dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, singleData);
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point([dict.get('longitude'), dict.get('latitude')]);
  var timeFormat = ee.Date(dict.get('time')).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  return ee.Feature(point, dict).set('timeFormat', timeFormat);
}));
```

Here is the link to rework the getRegion() output. [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/81f1a4f7568fd86a80561bd93a7e39c9)

Although I would suggest using reduceRegions() and add the date of the image to each feature. You can then export the feature collection as CSV.

```
var featureCollection = collection.map(function(image){
  var data = image.reduceRegions(gulbarga,'mean',30).map(function(feat){
    return ee.Feature(feat).set('time', image.get('system:time_start'), 'id', image.get('system:index'),
          'timeFormat', ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'),
          'latitude', feat.geometry().coordinates().get(1), 'longitude', feat.geometry().coordinates().get(0));
  });
  return data;
}).flatten();
```

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4d322fb22aeb484d7592d74a029d5e58)

You can export both (similar) feature collection to CSV in drive using:

```
Export.table.toDrive(featureCollection, 'exportAsCSV', 'GEE', 'CSVexport', 'CSV');
```